# What is the difference between допомагати and допомогти?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, non-native-speaker

Both words seem to be derived from the same root. Is one more favored in certain geographical areas? Or is one more closely related to Russian than the other?

Google translate list both as possible translations of "help," but doesn't differentiate their meanings in any significant way. Both have the same list of synonyms, except that допомагати also has "promote" and "avail."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Допомагати* is an [imperfective verb](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) ([aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfective_aspect)), and *допомогти* is a [perfective verb](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) ([aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfective_aspect)). These are typical variations of verbs in Slavic languages, [more in English here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect_in_Slavic_languages).

**Imperfective** verbs convey:

- actions and states in progress, just ongoing states and actions, with significant course (in opinion of the speaker);
- actions that serve as a background for other (perfective) actions, ex. *коли зателефонували, я читав книгу* — *I was reading the book when the telephone rang*;
- simultaneous actions, ex. *читатиму книгу, коли брат писатиме листа* — *I will be reading the book while brother will be writing the letter*;
- durative actions, lasting through some time, e.g. *кричав* — *he was shouting*, *смикатиметься* — *it will be vibrating*;
- aimless motions, ex. *ходжу* — *I am walking here and there*;
- multiple (iterative) actions, ex. *дописувати* — *to insert many times to the text*, *виходитимемо* — *we will go out (many times)*;
- actions heading towards no or an unspecified purpose: *писатиму листа* — *I will be writing the letter*;
- continuous states, ex. *стоятиму* — *I will be standing*.

**Perfective** verbs can refer to the past or to the future, but not to present actions – an action happening now cannot be ended, so it cannot be perfective. Perfective verbs convey:

- states and actions that are seen as having finished (even if a second ago) or becoming so in a future time-point, have no significant course, have short duration or are treated as a whole by the speaker, ex. *закричав* — *he shouted*, *перемішав* — *it will stir (only once)*;
- single-time actions, ex. *дописати* — *to insert to the text*, *вийшов* — *he went out*;
- actions whose goals are seen as having been achieved, even if with difficulty, ex. *прочитав* — *I have read*, *дочитала* — *she finished reading and found what she had sought*;
- circumstancial actions leading up to a state, ex. *покохала* — *she came to love*, *зрозумієш* — *you (sg.) will understand*, *взнаємо* — *we will get to know*;
- the beginning of the action or the state, ex. *встану* — *I will stand up (and I will stand)*, *почервонів* — *he reddened*;
  the end of the action or the state, ex. *доспівай* — *sing until the end*;
- actions executed in many places, on many objects or by many subjects at the same time, ex. *повиносив* — *he carried out (many things)*, *виламають* — *they will break out in many places*, *повирізати* — *to cut off many items*;
- actions or states when they are seen as constituting a lexeme-specific block of time (Aktionsart), ex. *постою* — *I will stand for a little time*, *побув* — *he was (there) for some time*.

Comment: _A postscript_. How to understand which verb is? Sometimes prefixes help but need just learn those verbs or use dictionaries.

Comment: I thought aspect only changed from prefixes. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, often not prefixes, but suffixes matter. *Носити* — *нести*, *возити* — *везти*, *зазначати* — *зазначити*, *пробачати* — *пробачити*, etc.